# Unexpected characters and Expected operators. Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have been trying out Power Apps of late and I ran into this issue creating a form that links to a SQL database: `Unexpected characters and Expected operators.` And for the life of me I don't know what characters and operators they are complaining about.

```
Text(DateDiff(
    TimeValue(Text(Dropdown1_2.Selected.Value) & ":" & Text(Dropdown1_3.Selected.Value)),
    TimeValue(Text(EndHrs_1.Selected.Value) & ":" & Text(EndMin_1.Selected.Value)),`Hours,"[$-en-US]00") & ":" &
Text(Mod(
    DateDiff(
    TimeValue(Text(Dropdown1_2.Selected.Value) & ":" & Text(Dropdown1_3.Selected.Value)),
    TimeValue(Text(EndHrs_1.Selected.Value) & ":" & Text(EndMin_1.Selected.Value)),Minutes
```

Comment: `Hours could be an issue??

Answer (score 0):

‘,Minutes’ at the end appears to be out of place being outside the last parenthesis. Typically the only thing after a paren that can be used is a semicolon to chain another statement or a period to “dig” into the schema.